# Configure Django with Apache

Tags: python, django, apache2

I am trying to get my Django application running under apache with mod_python but I do not know what is the problem.

my django project is under the directory `/srv/APCC`

Apache virtual host configs as following

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerAdmin my.mail@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /srv/APCC/

    <Location "/srv/APCC/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE APCC.settings
        PythonDebug Off
        PythonOption django.root /srv/APCC/
        PythonPath "['/srv/APCC/'] + sys.path"
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I hit `myhost.com:8000` I am getting the browser listing my django application files. What would be the problem here?

Comment: Why `mod_python` and not `mod_wsgi`? "[Support for mod_python has been deprecated, and will be removed in Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modpython/)."

Comment: There is no reason just i have used it before (2 years ago AFAIR)

Comment: Correct link for your Django application is http://myhost.com:8000/srv/APCC/

Comment: thnx sul4bh that is right. @Matthias I had reconfigured apache with mod_wsgi instead of mod_python and it works fine thnx

Comment: @Anas Rabei: Good to hear. Keep coding. :)